# Box Edit Integration

Tags: box-api

Is it possible to have direct edit links in a 3rd party product and have the files directly edit with the Box Edit plug-in? I'm already listing folders and files in our ERP app and would like to allow editing in the same way it's possible within the browser with the BoxEdit add-on.

Answer (score 1):

Box Edit currently isn't accessible programmatically by third parties. We may explore opening this up in the future but don't have any short term plans for doing so.

Answer (score -1):

Box does have a way of accessing the connected editors like Zoho and Gdocs through our API.  However, it's a tricky one to use, and not ready for public use yet.  If you're interested, you can email us at api [at] box [dot] com, and we may be able to give you beta access.

Comment: I'm not referring to the web-based editors, but to the Windows add-on that handles edit requests coming from the box.com web site - https://www.box.com/services/browse/official/box_edit.